# How do I find out what is causing Protractor synchronisation to slow down?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have an application that I am testing, and the e2e tests seem to hang and fail until I used `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true`. Preferably, I would rather fix the application then use this line. I know it's related to `$http` and `$timeout` based on this comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/9891d430aff477c5feb80ae01b48356866820132/lib/protractor.js#L158

```
  /**
   * If true, Protractor will not attempt to synchronize with the page before
   * performing actions. This can be harmful because Protractor will not wait
   * until $timeouts and $http calls have been processed, which can cause
   * tests to become flaky. This should be used only when necessary, such as
   * when a page continuously polls an API using $timeout.
   *
   * @type {boolean}
   */
```

Is there a method for pinpointing exactly what is causing this delay in my app?

Comment: Is it an angular application?

Comment: do you find solution for that ?